# Color filter query

Tags: mysql, sql, colors

I have 4 products, which I have applied colors
Products 1 and colors are Red, Blue and Pink
Products 2 and colors are Red, Blue and Yellow
Products 3 and colors are Red, Blue and Pink
Products 4 and colors are Red, Blue and Pink

Filter Red(4), Blue(4), Pink(3) and Yellow(1)

If user select Red show Product 1,2,3 and 4 its OK, but when I selected Yellow color also, than time I need show Product 2 only instead of Products 1,2,3,4
Please help me to write query in mysql

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you can provide a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) with a schema and sample data, we can understand the problem better and give you an answer much faster.  You should edit your answer rather than add more information as a comment.  You can also check out http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Gotta go for now, but you can fix the "ambiguous column"  error with `select p.products_id`

Comment: sorry, its missing, when I typing, I did fix, but no record, Red and Yellow color I did assign in Product 2 but no result in query

Comment: http://www.saisoftindia.com/_dev/index.php?cPath=22
if you select Beige, its show 4 products, because I did apply Beige color in 4 products, if you also select Yellow color, its showing no any products, but I did applied Yellow and Beige color both color in our one products, so need show 1 product'